# Uncaught Error: No define call for when loading non AMD script by require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have one non AMD javascript that contain my custom functions such as:

```
function getItemIndexById(items, id){
   for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
       if(items[i].ID == id) return i;
   }
   return false;
}
//more than one define custom function here.
```

Here main.js file :

```
requirejs.config({
 enforceDefine: true,
 paths: {
    "jquery": "libs/jquery/jquery-min",
    "underscore": "libs/underscore/underscore-min",
    "backbone": "libs/backbone/backbone-min",
    "custom" : "libs/scripts/customejs"
},
shim: {
    "underscore": {
        deps: [],
        exports: "_"
    },
    "backbone": {
        deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    }
}
});
```

Then I define in my view :

```
define(["jquery" ,
        "underscore" ,
        "backbone" ,
        "custom"
],function($ , _ , Backbone, Custom){
  //.....
}
```

I got an error in `Uncaught Error: No define call for custom`.

Do I have to convert my custom js into AMD? Could anyone explain me about this issue please. Thanks.

Comment: AMD cannot magically know what your script exports.

Comment: I have tried `exports : "Custom"` in `shim`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are those functions being defined in the global scope?  If so, are they namespaced?

Comment: Also, you are not telling us what is causing the error.  Is it a call to one of the functions defined in customejs?

Comment: Defined in global scope but no namespaced, before using require.js, I included it using `<script src = "customejs.js" ...>`.

Comment: Please have a look my updating above dear. I have defined it in main.js , to test whether it works or not, then I got `Uncaught Error: No define call for custom`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few common reasons for this issue described in  the [Require documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine).

In this case it is most likely because you are using `enforceDefine: true` and the "custom" js file does not call `define()`.

You will need to set `enforceDefine: false` or add a proper shim for the custom code.

The purpose of a shim is to allow Require to load non-AMD code. It works by loading the code and verifying that the script created a property in the global space, as defined by the `exports` property.

In your case, you could use `getItemIndexById` as the `exports` value:

```
shim: {
   "custom": {
      exports: "getItemIndexById"
   }
```

When you used `Custom` as the `exports` value it didn't work because your script did not create a variable called `Custom`

Read more about `shim` [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

Comment: proper shim? what proper shim should I add?

Comment: set `enforceDefine : false`, just not showing the error in my console, but it still caused `undefined` error.

Comment: oh, so I have to take one of the function name in my `custom` js to set as an export value?

Comment: @Domo yes, require will load your script, wait for it to execute and then test for the presence of `window[ exports ]`, in this case `window[ "getItemIndexById" ]`.  It would probably be better to make a more specific exports property that describes the contents of your code, like `myCustomLibrary` but I used the function that you presented as being in the code.

Comment: @Domo if this does solve your problem, please accept the answer. If not, I'm happy to continue to help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and also sorry for a late response because I just backed from my holiday.